# When does the save method in a Django model not run?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model that overrides the save method and looks like this:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    calls_logged = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    texts_logged = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    completed_logs = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.calls_logged >= 30 and self.texts_logged >= 50:
            self.completed_logs = True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What's supposed to happen is when the `Agent` reaches 30 calls and 50 texts, the `save()` method is supposed to change the `completed_logs` field to `True`. But when I recently checked my DB, an agent had reached over 30 calls and over 50 texts but `completed_logs` wasn't marked as completed. However, when I clicked 'Save' from within the admin, it updated the `completed_logs` field as expected.

So, my question is: is there ever a time that Django will not call the `save()` method on a model? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Show us where `save()` is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some methods that can update entries in the database without calling the `save` method. Some of which I can think of are:

- The `update` method of a queryset
- The `bulk_create` method of a queryset
- The `bulk_update` method of a queryset

Most likely the situation is that you call one of these methods, causing this situation to occur.

The best thing to do here is to **not** have `completed_logs` as a field but rather as a property:

```py
class Log(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    calls_logged = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    texts_logged = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    @property
    def completed_logs(self):
        return self.calls_logged >= 30 and self.texts_logged >= 50
```

Comment: I'm using `update` so that's probably it!! Thank you so much! I'm definitely going to switch to the property setup that you pointed out. Is there a place in the Django docs that specifies which model creation/update operations will not run the `save()` method?

Comment: @Ryan do note that having it as a property means it will not be saved in the database (is not needed to be stored anyway, it can simply be calculated) :). About knowing which methods don't call `save` you can try looking at the [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/), but I would say simply all methods that can update multiple objects at the same time don't call `save`.